# Issue with wavelink command (nextcord.py)

Tags: python, nextcord

So, I'm trying to make a "play" command to play videos from Youtube using nextcord.py and the wavelink library. But it gives me this error: "nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: source must be an AudioSource not YouTubeTrack". How could I fix this?

```
@bot.command(name="play", description="permette di mettere video da YouTube")
async def play(ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        vc: wavelink.player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

    await vc.play(search)
```